# /opt and sudo unzip to /opt, is it safe?

Tags: exploit, permissions, docker, bash, root

Usually we place things in `/opt` so they are owned by root but normal users can execute them. This prevents normal users modifying the binaries so they cannot execute arbitrary stuff. However, to put things there using `sudo unzip something.zip -d /opt` is a little bit dangerous as an exploit in `unzip` could then do anything with sudo capabilities. I created a temp folder instead and then extract there and `sudo mv folder /opt`, is this the safest solution?

from

```
RUN curl -sSL "${GRADLE_SDK_URL}" -o gradle.zip \
    && echo "${GRADLE_ZIP_SHA256_HASH} *gradle.zip" | shasum -a 256 --check \
    && sudo unzip gradle.zip -d /opt  \
    && rm -rf $TEMPD \
    && rm -rf gradle.zip
```

to

```
RUN curl -sSL "${GRADLE_SDK_URL}" -o gradle.zip \
    && echo "${GRADLE_ZIP_SHA256_HASH} *gradle.zip" | shasum -a 256 --check \
    && TEMPD=$(mktemp -d) \
    && unzip gradle.zip -d ${TEMPD}  \
    && sudo mv ${TEMPD} /opt \
    && rm -rf $TEMPD \
    && rm -rf gradle.zip
```

Comment: BTW you could unzip it in a build container and then copy the expanded directory in a staged build. But I think in any case the file is trusted and checksumed, there is not really a big risk.

Comment: Do you need to change the ownership of the files to `root`? Currently they'll be owned by the user running the command, and `mv` to `/opt` won't change the ownership...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is safer to run `unzip` without root permissions and then move the extracted contents to their final destination. However, if you suspect that the file which you are providing to `unzip` is malicious or has been tampered with, then it may still be a serious security issue if you plan to run the files in `/opt` with root privileges. Additionally, there is the possibility that a malicious process running with the same privileges as `curl` could modify the files in the temporary directory after they have been written to but before they are moved to a system directory and owned by root.

Note that verifying the hash, even if it's a cryptographic hash, does not provide protection against malicious tampering if it is distributed through the same channel that the data is. Instead, you should verify the digital signature. Unfortunately, I don't think Gradle uses digital signatures, [just hashes](https://gradle.org/release-checksums/).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the source and content of the zip archive are trusted enough.

`mv` is part of the standard utils. These are old and well tested. They also don't change much. If you look at the list of vulnerabilities of `mv` or `util-linux` or whatever flavour you have, you will see very few vulnerabilities. It is also a small, simple program.

`unzip` is quite error-free lately, but there have been quite a number of vulnerabilities (DoS,     Exec Code Overflow,     +Priv, Dir. Trav. etc.). Furthermore `unzip` is more complex than `mv`.

Based on that, I would say that the `unzip` unprivileged locally and the `mv` as root after that is more secure.